# Writing the results of the for loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, dataframe

We were trying to write the results from a for loop. We tried to use `write.table`, `as.data.frame` and other solutions, but with no success. We expect to have a data frame.

Currently we have only the loop, that shows year and values from a matrix which are bigger than 50. Looks like that:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(dobowe1)) {
  if(dobowe1[i,4]>50) {
    cat(dobowe1[i,"rok"],dobowe1[i,4], "\n")
  }
}
```

**Note:** We don't do programming a lot, so it's hard to use other solutions from the questions that already beed asked.

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Answer (score 2):

Try to save each element to the vector, like here:

```
tabela <- numeric(nrow(dobowe1))
for (i in 1:nrow(dobowe1)) {
  if(dobowe1[i,4]>50) {
    tabela[i] <- paste(dobowe1[i,"rok"],dobowe1[i,4])
  }
}
as.data.frame(tabela)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to visually inspect a subset of your matrix, you can just print out a filtered subset:

```
# create the filter:

> f <- dobowe1[,4] > 50

# use the filter to subset (index) your data.frame:

> dobowe1[f,c("rok", whatever-4th-var-is-called)]

This will automatically print it out. Or you can write it to a file with ?write.table
```